# JQuery Validation

Tags: jquery, validation

```
var formValidationRules = {
    rules: {
        password: {
            required: true,
            remote: '/account/delete'
        }
    },
    messages: {
        "password": { required: "Please enter your password", remote: "Invalid password, try again." }
    }
};
```

I wrote such validation, but I found out the the Validation will check for each event for
the remote and the required.

I would like to perform such task only when submitting,
(no blur, no keyup) - what is the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See the `onfocusout` and `onkeyup` [options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options):

```
var formValidationRules = {
        rules: {
                password: {
                        required: true,
                        remote: sitemap.accountSettings.validatePassword
                }
        },
        //wording
        messages: {
                "password": { required: "Please enter your password", remote: "Invalid password, try again." }
        }
        onfocusout: false,
        onkeyup: false
};
```

Comment: sounds good but such code won't cause submit at all....
so even pressing the submit won't cause the validation...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which validation plugin you are using but if you use the basic [validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) from jquery you just add the following code.

My form only validates on form submit and this seems like what you are wanting.

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function() { form.submit(); }
});
```